# NSGA2: Multi-objective Optimization Problem using Pymoo package in Python

Tags: python, optimization, pymoo

I have been working on 3 objective optimization problem and my goal is to minimize all three functions based on 3 design variables.I have written a python code which works great for 2 objective problem but it doesnt give me non-dominated set of solutions for 3 objective problem and especially when the lower and upper bound looks as such.
I need help regarding what needs to be done. I will really appreciate some help.
Im attaching the code below

"""CODE""""

```
from pymoo.core.problem import Problem
import numpy as np
from deap import benchmarks
from pymoo.optimize import minimize
from pymoo.algorithms.moo.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.factory import get_sampling, get_crossover, get_mutation

class ProblemWrapper(Problem):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(n_var=3, n_obj=3,  xl=np.array([2400,22800,298]), xu=np.array([2500,24700,490]))

    
    def _evaluate(self, designs, out, *args, **kwargs):
        res=[]
        for design in designs:
            res.append(benchmarks.kursawe(design))
            
        out['F'] = np.array(res)
algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=100,
                  sampling=get_sampling("real_random"),
                  crossover=get_crossover("real_sbx", prob=0.9, eta=15),
                  mutation=get_mutation("real_pm", eta=20),
                  eliminate_duplicates=True)

stop_criteria = ('n_gen',100)

problem=ProblemWrapper()
res = minimize(problem=problem,
                   algorithm=algorithm,
                   termination=stop_criteria,
                   seed=1,
                   pf=problem.pareto_front(use_cache=False),
                   save_history=True
                )

from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter
plot = Scatter()
plot.add(problem.pareto_front(), plot_type="line", color="black", alpha=0.7)
plot.add(res.F, facecolor="none", edgecolor="red")
plot.show()
```

[image: Here is the result of the above code]

Comment: I looks like there is an optimal point that is better on all objectives than the others, your problem has a singleton as Pareto set/front